# How to iterate and remove keys from Map<String , Map<String, Set<String>>>

Tags: java, collections, iterator, hashmap, set

I am having map this way,

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> sampleMap = new Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>>();
```

and the data in this map would be this way,

```
sampleMap={2014={A=[1, 2], B=[3], 2015={A=[1,2], B=[1,2], 2016={A=[1,2], B=[3,4]}};
```

I want to remove the key's from the map based on this input: `List<String> filter;` with values this way,

```
filterArray : [2014, 2015]
```

i.e, first iterate through arraylist values one by one, verify if the arraylist value matches with any of the key in Hashmap.

- if key is matched ignore it.
- if key is not matched, I just want to remove that key from the map.

i.e, I always want to keep only matched keys in map, comparing with the input value passed.

In this case, as I have arraylist values this way,[2014,2015],

**2014,2015 keys only to be in my map. So,**

Data to be before removal:

```
sampleMap={2014={A=[1, 2], B=[3], 2015={A=[1,2], B=[1,2], 2016={A=[1,2], B=[3,4]}};
```

Data to be after removel:

```
sampleMap={2014={A=[1, 2], B=[3], 2015={A=[1,2], B=[1,2]}};
```

I tried this way, However I just want to know is this is the correct approch, or is it is prone to any of the exceptions?

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String , Map<String, Set<String>>>> iter = sampleMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String , Map<String, Set<String>>> entry = iter.next();
    logger.info("Keys : " + entry.getKey());
    if (filterArray.equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getKey())) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: `filterArray.equalsIgnoreCase(..)` ... I wonder how that works in your example. Can you explain that, please? (what is `filterArray`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `retainAll()` on the keySet:

```
map.keySet().retainAll(list);
```

Comment: +1 Good solution.  Won't work if you need case insensitive (which from his data doesn't seem necessary, but his example had it.).  I didn't realize that the keyset updated the original map!

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable.  I might have a couple pieces of advice.

First of all, whenever I see nested collections I always wonder if there should be a class or two in there.  If this is a one-time task then don't worry about it, but if you want to reuse this code you might want to think about creating a class for your inner map/set... but if it's really this simple then it's no big deal.

Secondly if you are using Java 8, using a list comprehension for filtering would perform better (Because it would automatically thread your compares) and would be cleaner.  I can give you the groovy solution for what you are trying to do, but I'm not familiar enough with java 8 list comprehensions to do it correctly.

```
def filteredStructure=structure.findAll{entry->entry.key.equalsIgnoreCase("2014") || entry.key.equalsIgnoreCase("2015"))
```

The java version should be really similar.